# Internal Server Error 500.24

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web in IIS Express.

When I launch it, I see following message in the browser:

[image: Screenshot]

Translation from German: *ASP.NET setting was recognized, which is invalid in the "integrated" managed pipeline mode.
Probable causes:
"system.web/identity@impersonate" is set to "true".*

How can I fix this?

**Update 1:** The Properties panel:

[image: Properties panel]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed the error by changing following files:

`vwd.webinfo` (added `useClassicPipelineMode` tag):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
  Visual Studio global web project settings.
-->
<VisualWebDeveloper>

  <iisExpressSettings windowsAuthentication="enabled" anonymousAuthentication="enabled" useClassicPipelineMode="true"/>
</VisualWebDeveloper>
```

`Web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 7):

In Visual Studio, select your web project in the solution explorer, then open the properties window (keyboard shortcut F4)

You should be seeing a list of properties to configure your IIS Express Server.

Change the option "Managed Pipeline Mode" from `Integrated` to `Classic`

Comment: That's strange... I guess Visual Studio 2013 Express doesn't offer that option. Then your only option will be to change the web.config accordingly...

Comment: I changed the application pool for my web app to `Clr2ClassicAppPool` in the `C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` file, but when I launch the web app in Visual Studio, the application pool for that app is set again to `Clr4IntegratedAppPool`. How can I change this in `web.config`?

Comment: Try this command `appcmd set app /app.name:ExampleApp/ /applicationPool:Clr4ClassicAppPool`. Also you can try installing the full IIS version.

Answer (score -1):

IIS Manager -> application Pools -> right click site -> Advanced Settings

Set Enable 32-bit applications to True
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dErD0.png)